# .htaccess redirection 302 on no longer exists folder

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I have old pages :
http://www.example.com/search/old-search-1.php
http://www.example.com/search/old-search-2.php
...
http://www.example.com/search/old-search-10000.php

That I wanted to reditect (301) to home.

I try with .htaccess (placed on /) with this :
...

```
RewriteRule ^/search/$ http://www.example.com [R=301,L]
```

But don't do anything, I get 404 http headers when I access to http://www.example.com/search/old-search-2.php

Other point, search/ folder no longer exists.

How could I get this 301 redirection ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Try this redirect :

```
 RedirectMatch 302 ^/search/.*$ http://example.com/
```

Comment: 404 error too.
The point is that if I create a "search/" folder and put .htaccess in it. The redirection work.
But it is not the goal because this folder no longer exists.

Comment: Try clearing your browser cache. the redirect should work in root/.htaccess.

Comment: Browser cache is cleared but this do the same. It don't work from the root if the folder does not exists.